# FFTW for Windows/Eclipse/Android

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, fftw

I am developing a `.cpp` file in the `JNI` folder for an `Android` project integration and I need to use the `FFTW` library to manipulate the spectrum of a signal. I can't find any good documentation about compiling/installing these kind of libraries in `Eclipse` (I am using `Cygwin` to compile files).

My question is if any one knows any reliable tutorial or how to allocate files from the prebuilt version of the `FFTW`. I am using Windows 7.